# SQL - Order by time, then text on beginning

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query below :

> `SELECT DISTINCT TimeSched from tbl_schedule`

It returns this result:

```
TimeSched

Rest Day
11:00 AM - 08:00 PM
No Schedule
09:00 AM - 06:00 PM
10:00 AM - 07:00 PM
```

When I use ORDER BY TimeSched, it returns this result:

```
TimeSched

09:00 AM - 06:00 PM
10:00 AM - 07:00 PM
11:00 AM - 08:00 PM
No Schedule
Rest Day
```

However, my desired result is I want 'Rest Day' and 'No Schedule' on the first and second row by default, then followed by the order of schedules in ascending order. As seen below :

```
TimeSched

Rest Day
No Schedule
09:00 AM - 06:00 PM
10:00 AM - 07:00 PM
11:00 AM - 08:00 PM
```

Comment: that is the correct behaviour sorting alphanumeric

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for your feedback. However, is it possible to achieve my desired result?

Comment: what you can do is append a prefix for No Schedule and Restday with 01 when ordering.. so 01No will go 1, 01R will go next then your 09 to 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question.

```
SELECT CASE TimeSched WHEN 'Restday' THEN 1 WHEN 'No Schedule' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END 
AS TimeSked, TimeSched ORDER BY TimeSked, TimeSched
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
select * from timetable
order by 
iif(timesched in ('No Schedule','Rest Day'),'01' + timesched,timesched)
```

> Append a prefix for No Schedule and Restday with
>   01 when ordering.. so 01No will go 1, 01R will go next then your 09 to
>   24

Comment: Thank you Sir, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TimeSched 
FROM tbl_schedule
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN timesched LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
         timesched;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of the below code :

```
    DECLARE @TimeSched TABLE
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),TimeSched VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO @TimeSched
    VALUES
    ('Rest Day'),
    ('11:00 AM - 08:00 PM'),
    ('No Schedule'),
    ('09:00 AM - 06:00 PM'),
    ('10:00 AM - 07:00 PM')

    SELECT * FROM @TimeSched
    ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN TimeSched ='Rest Day' THEN 1
        WHEN TimeSched ='No Schedule' THEN 2
        ELSE 3 END
```